# How to use Subqueries.in

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

How to express such HQL query via criteria API?

```
select a from A a where
(select b.prop from B b where b.id = a.parent) in ('1', '2', '3')
```

List of ids is passed as parameter.

Here is my subquery:

```
DetachedCriteria subQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(B.class, "b").
                .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("b.id", "a.parent"))
                .setProjection(Projections.property("b.prop"));
```

*Subqueries.in* and *propertyIn* work the opposite way (prop in subquery, not subquery in prop as i need). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Restrictions.in(...)`.

```
List<Integer> values=new ArrayList<Integer>();
values.add(1);
values.add(2);
values.add(3);

DetachedCriteria subQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(B.class, "b").
            .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("b.id", "a.parent"))
            .setProjection(Projections.property("b.prop")).
            .add(Restrictions.in("b.prop", values);
```